# Transpose columns to rows with column header in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Have tried to convert the columns to rows in oracle but the column headers should be the first column values.

*Note: The select statement with WHERE clause*. Have tried PIVOT and UNPIVOT but unfortunately I am not getting the desired output.

[image]

It should be converted to

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot, as you said.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (column1, column2, column3) as
  2    (select 385, 0, 29 from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select *
  4  from test
  5  unpivot (value for type in (column1, column2, column3));

TYPE         VALUE
------- ----------
COLUMN1        385
COLUMN2          0
COLUMN3         29

SQL>
```